# Disable zoom on GDM, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: login-screen, gdm, zooming

Ubuntu seems to detect that my laptop has a high resolution screen and, by default, sets everything to a 200% zoom.  I prefer to set this back to no zoom, but with larger font sizes.  This was no problem for Ubuntu/Gnome itself, but GDM does not seem to inherit these settings.  Moreover, figuring out how to configure GDM seems like an absolute nightmare.

How can I disable the zoom feature?  Or should I just switch from GDM to a different login manager?

This is distinct from questions about Grub resolution.  Grub uses my native resolution just fine.  The UI is scaled up separately.  This also has nothing to do with trying to enable fractional scaling.

Comment: @zwets this is unrelated to questions about Grub's resolution, see my edit above

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix With all due respect, did you even read the question?  This has nothing to do with enabling fractional scaling.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Right, but I am satisfied with non-fractional scaling and have that working fine on my desktop.  The problem is GDM.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Unfortunately it does not.  It scales the fonts (in fact I have it set to 1.25) but does not disable the doubling of all the UI elements.

Comment: I've retracted my close vote and deleted the comments.